# Como capturar um erro ocorrido em um servidor webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Eu tenho um servidor onde roda um serviço de WebAPI, no cliente eu executo a chamada a uma URL de POST assim:

```
try
{
   HttpWebRequest request;

   request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

   request.Method = "POST";
   request.Proxy = null;
   request.ContentType = "application/json";

   byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DATA);
   Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
   newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
   newStream.Close();

   request.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

   //QUERO LER O ERRO AQUI
}
```

No servidor eu faço o tratamento assim:

```
try
{

...

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

   return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,ex);
}
```

O problema é que no cliente ele vem uma `exception` dizendo que tomou erro 500, eu sei que a `exception` não "vem" do servidor, que é gerada no cliente, mas eu gostaria de saber como eu pego o `inner` todo gerado no `CreateErrorResponse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por defeito, os detalhes da excepcao ocorrida no servidor não são colocados na resposta HTTP. Isto serve para não mostrar detalhes da implementação do servidor ao cliente - é uma medida de segurança. Quanto menos o cliente souber acerca das entranhas do servidor, melhor.

Os detalhes de excepção só são colocados na resposta HTTP ser o cliente for local, ou seja, se o cliente e o servidor estiveram no mesmo computador.

No entanto, se esta API for para consumo interno, podes escolher exibir os detalhes da excepção para *todos* os clientes, usando [`HttpConfiguration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpconfiguration.includeerrordetailpolicy%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

No ficheiro `WebApiConfig.cs`, adiciona:

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

No servidor, a excepção vai ser convertida para uma instância de [`HttpError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httperror%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) e serializada no corpo da resposta. Então, do lado do cliente, basta converter de volta para `HttpError`.

Nota: é preferível usar o `HttpClient` em vez de `WebRequest` para fazer pedidos HTTP, pois tem uma API de alto nível e evita lidar directamente com byte streams. Esse código todo pode ser escrito assim:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("url", data);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var error = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpError>();
    }
    else
    {
        var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Model>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sub a alteração sugerida para os servidor, mas não entendi onde vejo a mensagem da 'execption', continuo capturando no 'cach', mas não acho nada nela. Pode me dar um exemplo de onde achar isso? Pode ser com o 'WebRequest' ou 'HttpClient'

Comment: @user3517631 Ja actualizei a resposta, onde mostro como ler o corpo da resposta HTTP e converter para uma instancia de `HttpError`. Esse objecto contem os detalhes da excepcao.

Comment: Eu não consigo achar essa classe `HttpError` em nenhuma DLL, você pode me mostrar como eu capturo o erro `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: @user3517631 experimenta importar o nuget [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/)

Comment: eu já tinha tentado, não apareceu, na vdd ele quebrou a referencia da minha Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: @user3517631 Esse nuget tem de funcionar. Olha aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ScY79s

Comment: Se so precisares da mensagem, tambem podes converter a resposta para um JObject e extrair a mensagem assim: `(await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JObject>()).Value<string>("ExceptionMessage")`. Nao testei mas julgo que funcione.